# Duplicated events from Fabric stream into Firebase-> Google Big Query streaming

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, google-fabric

We've noticed, that in raw Google Big Query (gbq) data from firebase appeared duplicates. After a short investigation it seemed obvious, that problem is caused by Fabric - same events differed by a value of a firebase_event_origin field (app|fab). I've found no answer how to stop events from fabric stream in GBQ Firebase import.

Have anyone solved this problem already?

Image:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, that happen to be easy - our coder set up an integration between Fabric and Firebase. So, to stop receiving Firebase events you just should go to Firebase console settings, open 'Integrations' pane and proceed to 'Fabric'. There you just need to turn off option 'Send Fabric events to Google Analytics for Firebase'.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZwCI.png)